# How to use conditional operators in mongodb queries in c++

Tags: c++, mongodb, conditional-operator

I don't find how to use conditional operators `("$in", "$gt", "$lt"...)` in queries when using **MongoDB C++** driver?

Example of javascript implementation:

```
db.collection.find( { field : { $in : array } } );
db.collection.find( { "field" : { $gt: value1, $lt: value2 } } );
```

edit: [C++ documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=21270051) answers for $gt/$lt operators but says nothing about $in:

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood, but the link in your question actually does give an example. The sixth entry in the table shows the following relation between the javascript and C++ driver:

*Javascript*

```
db.users.find({'age':{$gt:33},{$lte:40}})
```

*C++*

```
auto_ptr<DBClientCursor> cursor = 
  c.query("mydb.users", QUERY("age"<<GT<<33<<LTE<<40));
```

Comment: Exact, I don't know why I added $gt/$lt in my question. My problem was for $in operator.