# How to write simple queries in MongoDB with C++?

Tags: c++, mongodb

I am new to Mongo and am using it with the C++ api.  How do you exactly write queries? I can't find any reference.  I got the example to run a blank query. From what I was able to gather by searching, I got the below but its not correct.  How can I find all documents where the volume field is less than a 1000?  How do I run a query on multiple fields? For example, volume<1000 and otherfield=false.

```
mongo::BSONObj query("volume" << mongo::LT << 1000);
auto_ptr<mongo::DBClientCursor> cursor = c.query("db.collection", query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to my question here:[How to use conditional operators in mongodb queries in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408598/how-to-use-conditional-operators-in-mongodb-queries-in-c)

Below shows how to filter based on more than one field

```
auto_ptr<mongo::DBClientCursor> cursor = c.query(dbcol, QUERY("field1"<<mongo::LT<<1000<<"field2"<<mongo::LT<<0.02));
```